# Proof of $L(E,1)/Ω(E)=1/8$ for elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3-x/ \Bbb{Q}$?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, l-functions

Let

- $E:y^2=x^3-x$ be an elliptic curve over $ \Bbb{Q}$ and
- $ω_E=dx/2y=dx/2\sqrt{x^3-x}$.

Then
$$
\begin{split}
\Omega(E)&=\int_{E(\Bbb{R})} ω_E\\
\\
&=2\int\limits_1^{+\infty} dx/\sqrt{x^3-x} 
\end{split}
$$
**Question**. Let the Hasse-Weil $L$-function be $L(E,1)$.
How can I prove that
$$
L(E,1)/\Omega(E)=1/8\text{ ?} \label{1}\tag{$\star$}
$$
If you know any reference (★) is proved, I'll appreciate if you could show me how to calculate (★).

Comment: You can do so by using module symbols, as it is the value of the modular symbol (suitably normalised with respect to your period) evaluated at 0. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406055/how-do-you-compute-modular-symbols/406062#406062) here for how this is done. [Cremona's book](https://johncremona.github.io/book/fulltext/index.html) is a good source for the basics of how to verify BSD for elliptic curves.

Comment: If we admit $L(E,1)＝0.65551438837・・・$ and $Ω(E)＝5.24411510858・・・$ , from this, can we say $L(E,1)/Ω(E)＝1/8$ without using computer ?

Comment: In Cremona's book (somewhere around §2.8?), there is a proof using modular symbols that $L(E,1)/\Omega_E$ is a rational number with denominator bounded by $(p+1)-a_p$ for $p$ a prime of good reduction. Hence, approximating that number to this precision will give it you exactly.

Comment: I'm confused. For $p＝2$, the elliptic curve has good reduction, so the denominator is smaller than $3$ ? Which prime $p$ you take ?

Comment: It's equation (2.8.10) in Cremona. There is an additional factor of $2$ there. By the way, Magma tells me that the $L$-ratio is $1/4$. (It depends on how you define $\Omega_E$.)